# Apt-get not working after setting proxy in ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hi Im using ubuntu server.
I have set the proxies using :

```
echo "export http_proxy='http://username:password@proxyIP:port/'" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

Ive set up http, https and ftp proxies. `Wget` works fine but `apt-get` does not connect.
Please help!

Comment: What error do you get when you run `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `apt-get` but I've never got **yum** to work with the environment variables. Instead, I've had to set the proxy via its [config](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html).

Here's a related post for the **apt-get** conf:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy

Also... how awesome is plain-text passwords sitting in a file that's public-readable by default! (or environment variables and bash history for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update .bashrc and apt.conf for this to work.

Following link would explain this in detail.
http://codewithgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/11/configure-apt-get-to-work-from-behind.html

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is  set to ignore the system default proxy settings.

To set the proxy you have to go to /etc/apt/apt.conf file and add following lines:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyIP:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@proxyIP:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyIP:port/";
```

---

You can create a script also to set this and unset this when ever you want.

Create a script aptProxyOn.sh

```
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root";
  exit 1;
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ]
  then

  printf \
  "Acquire::http::proxy \"http://$1:$2/\";\n\
   Acquire::ftp::proxy \"ftp://$1:$2/\";\n\
   Acquire::https::proxy \"https://$1:$2/\";\n" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxies;
  sudo cp /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxies /etc/apt/apt.conf

  else

  printf "Usage $0 <proxy_ip> <proxy_port>\n";

fi
```

---

To remove proxy, create a script with name aptProxyOff.sh

```
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root";
  exit 1;
fi


printf "" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxies;
sudo cp /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxies /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

---

Give permission for both the files to run. `chmod +x aptProxyOn.sh aptProxyOff.sh`

---

You have to run them in the following way.

Proxy On -

```
sudo ./aptProxyOn.sh username:password@proxyIP port
```

Proxy Off -

```
sudo ./aptProxyOff.sh
```

---

**Tip**:
If you have *@* in your username or password, it will not work directly.
You have to use URL encoding of *@* which is *%40*. But while passing commandline arguments you can't use *%40*, you have to use *%%40*

Answer (score 0):

**This worked out best for me:**

switch in to the **/etc/apt directory**

Edit the following file , if the file is not present this command will create one

gedit /apt.conf.d/apt.conf

**and add the following line**

Aquire::http::proxy "http://[proxy-server]:[port]";

Aquire::https::proxy "https://[proxy-server]:[port]";